# Channel Ratings Comments Spam

Tags: devdemon, channel-ratings

Hi I use Channel Ratings with comments on my website, but lately I'm receiving 'spammed'   ratings with comments about viagra!!!
Do you have a way to prevent this from happening??

Best regards

Dave@Daliz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Channel Ratings uses ExpressionEngine's native commenting system, you should look at [general solutions for combatting comment spam](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/security/spam_protection.html), including [enabling Captcha as @gabriel_b suggests](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/25021/1978).

I have had success in the past using Ben Croker's [Snaptcha](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snaptcha) add-on to prevent automated spam attacks.

Comment: Thanks, I i'm using Snaptcha at the moment to adres this problem, works lik a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you enable Captcha-s? This should prevent you from getting automated SPAM